# Internet Explorer 8 doesn't load pages opened in new Windows

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't load pages opened in new Windows, but does in same window and tabs.

Windows 7, reinstalled Internet Explorer 8, and updated.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to reset IE settings? You can do this from, IE Options->Advanced Tab->Reset.

Keep in mind that, doing this will disable all 3rd party add-ons and reset your settings.

Comment: yep, tried that

Answer (score 0):

1. Internet Options -> General
2. Click on "Settings" button for the Tabs section
3. Make sure that "Always open pop-ups in a new window" is checked under "When a pop-up is encountered".
4. Restart Browser

Optionally if you want another program to open a new window (say you click a link from within outlook) you can check "A new window" under "Open links from other programs in:"